# memberships section read back empty from API

Tags: asana, asana-api

I'm having trouble attempting to read back a Task's **Section** property.  The online API docs info on sections ([api-reference/sections](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/sections)) state:

> The ‘memberships’ property when getting a task will return the information for the section or the column under ‘section’ in the response.

When trying *opt_fields* request type, the json returned is empty either memberships:[{}] or memberships:[{},{}]

*/projects//tasks?&opt_fields=name,notes,completed,completed_at,assignee,assignee_status,due_on,projects,modified_at,memberships"*

When trying *opt_expand* request type, I don't see any json 'memberships' parts returned

*"/projects//tasks?&opt_expand=memberships&opt_fields=name,notes,completed,completed_at,assignee,assignee_status,due_on,projects,modified_at"*

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you query a task, the response will include `memberships` by default (you do not need to add an `opt_field`).

For example, when you request a task `GET /tasks/task-id`, the response will look like this:

`{
  "data": {
    "id": 123456789,
    "assignee": null,
    "assignee_status": "later",
    "completed": false,
    "completed_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-04-03T19:03:43.840Z",
    "due_at": null,
    "due_on": "2017-10-09",
    "hearted": false,
    "hearts": [],
    "memberships": [
      {
        "project": {
          "id": 123456789,
          "name": "Test Project"
        },
        "section": {
          "id": 123456789,
          "name": "I'm a section:"
        }
      }
...
  }
}`

You can get the memberships of all tasks in a project by using `opt_expand=membership` in the request:  `GET /projects/project-id/tasks?opt_expand=membership`.

The membership includes the task's project and section.  If the task is not in a section, it will return `"section":{null}`.

You can also query for sections in a project:  `GET /projects/project-id/sections`.

Note that sections are actually tasks (with a colon at the end of the name) in the Asana data model.  Also note that the membership of a section will be itself, which is a little confusing.

Comment: Are you saying that 'memberships' info only gets returned when performing a **single task** GET?  I was trying/hoping to obtain this info in the fetch of the collection of tasks in a project (hence the /projects/tasks? query).  The Asana API tool seems to imply you can obtain this field in that case, hence my confusion with the entry returned but empty value.  (Thanks for the response).

Comment: In addition to getting the membership for a single task, you can also get the memberships for all tasks returned from all tasks in a project:  `GET  /projects/project-id/tasks?opt_expand=membership`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include getting memberships for all tasks in a project.

Answer (score -1):

If you want both sections and projects under "membership":
/tasks?&opt_fields=memberships.(project|section)"

If you need only section name : 
/tasks?&opt_fields=memberships.section.name"

Source: https://forum.asana.com/t/get-all-project-tasks-with-their-section/15606